# Generic Spring 3 "Converter" Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page...I get district.id in post handler...I want to auto populate District object automatically through Converter. I have lot of entity class, so I don't want to write lot of Converter for all entity class.

```
    <form:form commandName ="village" action="village.html" >
        <label><fmt:message key="location.district"/></label>
        <form:select path="district.id">
          <form:options items="${districtList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="districtName"/>
        </form:select>
        <input type = "submit" value="Save" class="submit-button" /> </form:form>
  </form:form>
```

I followed this link...but not worked...:-(
http://digitaljoel.nerd-herders.com/2011/06/15/spring-converterfactory-implementation/

please give me some real example that works...

Answer (score 0):

have you considered `BeanWrapper` interface in spring. This is similar to commons-beanutils,

you can use this interface with `BeanWrapperImpl` class to read properties from the request object and populate the associated model.

```
final BeanWrapper sourceBean = new BeanWrapperImpl(obj);
final PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = sourceBean.getPropertyDescriptors();
for (final PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
// create a destinationBean
// iterate through each property from the sourceBean and set it to destinationBean.
}
```

this way you can copy the field values from one bean to another, if you have a request object which you are dealing with you can look at struts2 framework, else try using  the code above with springconverters (which can convert basic types) and build you own converter.